# Quickie about 'case' sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, case

Does the case statement work like "if - else if" or like "if - if"?

Let's say, I write

```
...ORDER BY CASE WHEN agentid=@agentid THEN 4 WHEN status='GOLD' THEN 3 WHEN status='SILVER' THEN 2 WHEN status='BASIC' THEN 1 END DESC
```

Will an entry where the agentid is @agentid and the status is GOLD be **7** or **4** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively an else-if; The `CASE` statement will return the 1st matching value, so when `agentid=@agentid` is satisfied evaluations stops without examining the other `WHEN` conditions & 4 will be returned.